# How to resolve angular cli postinstall error

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular-cli, npm-install

Can someone help how to resolve below error?

```
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! @angular/cli@8.0.6 postinstall: `node ./bin/postinstall/script.js`
npm ERR! spawn %AppData%\npm ENOENT
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Run `npm cache clean --force` then `npm install` as an **Administrator**.